# Filter columns where one of the values is 0

Tags: python, numpy

I want to filter columns where one of the values in the column is 0. So

```
>>> test = numpy.array([[3,2,3], [0,4,2],[2,3,2]])
>>> test
[[3 2 3
  0 4 2
  2 3 2]]
```

would become

```
>>> test[somefilter]
[[2 3
  4 2
  3 2]]
```

I thought this could be done by

```
>>> test[:, ~numpy.any(0, axis=0)]
```

but this just gets the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to filter columns where one value is 0, you could've used `all`:

```
test[:, test.all(axis=0)]
```

or

```
test[:, numpy.all(test, axis=0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `numpy.any(0, axis=0)` tests whether any value in "`0`" is nonzero, so it will always evaluate `False`. Therefore, `~numpy.any(0, axis=0)` will always evaluate `True`, which gets cast to the index `1`, so you always get column 1 back.

Instead you want to look for columns in `test` where there are *not any zeros in the row values*:

```
test[:, ~numpy.any(test == 0, axis=0)]
```

Or equivalently, where *all row values are nonzero* using `np.all()`:

```
test[:, np.all(test, axis=0)]

#[[2, 3]
# [4, 2]
# [3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `numpy.any(0, axis=0)` always evaluates to 0. You need to pass in `test==0` to check for values of 0 in `test`.

How about this?

```
In [37]: x = numpy.any(test==0, axis=0)

In [38]: test[:,numpy.where(x== False)[0]]
Out[38]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 2],
       [3, 2]])
```

**Edit**

I'm gonna leave this as a more roundabout way of doing the same thing, but I think `ali_m`'s answer is more elegant and stylistically closer to to the asker's code.

Answer (score 0):

How about not using numpy?

```
arr=[[3,2,3], [0,4,2],[2,3,2]]

for lis in arr:
    for i,num in enumerate(lis):
        if num==0:
            for chk in arr:
                del chk[i]

print arr
```

results:

```
[[2, 3], [4, 2], [3, 2]]
```